How do I update a package on conda forge?
How do I update a package on conda-forge? I'm trying to install the newest version of neuralprophet, but it is outdated on the conda-forge channel.
There are pull requests on the feedstock github page, but how do I merge these? Can I merge these, or are special permissions needed?
As a side note, I've also tried to get this package from the anaconda channel but the windows version is very outdated.
As a last resort I could install the package via pip but this creates all kinds of issues.

If you are not part of the respective feedstock's project on Github (in particular, if you do not have push access there), then you can't merge a pull request on the feedstock's project. So, other than (1) becoming a project member on the feedstock with necessary access rights, (2) waiting, or (3) installing the package via a different source, you will be out of luck.

In situations like these when I need to resort to pip install on a conda env, I usually do a --dry-run install first, see which package dependencies pip tries to install, install these dependencies manually via conda, and then finally install (only) the one package of interest via pip. In this way I try to mix pip and conda installs as little as possible. So far, this strategy worked reasonably well (but I did not try it with the package you mentioned).

You cannot merge the PRs unless you are a maintainer of the github repo.
For situations where the package you need is not available or outdated on the anaconda repo, you can install all of the dependencies that are required using conda, and then install the package via PIP.  This puts the package as the only part that is not managed by conda.
Looking at the dependencies, you can install most of them via conda:
# Windows
conda install -c conda-forge `
"numpy>=1.25.0,<2.0.0" `
"pandas>=2.0.0" `
"pytorch>=2.0.0,<2.4.0" `
"pytorch-lightning>=2.0.0,<2.4.0" `
"tensorboard>=2.11.2" `
"torchmetrics>=1.0.0" `
"typing-extensions>=4.5.0" `
"holidays>=0.41,<1.0" `
"captum>=0.6.0" `
"matplotlib>=3.5.3" `
"plotly>=5.13.1" `
"python-kaleido==0.2.1"

# Linux
conda install -c conda-forge \
"numpy>=1.25.0,<2.0.0" \
"pandas>=2.0.0" \
"pytorch>=2.0.0,<2.4.0" \
"pytorch-lightning>=2.0.0,<2.4.0" \
"tensorboard>=2.11.2" \
"torchmetrics>=1.0.0" \
"typing-extensions>=4.5.0" \
"holidays>=0.41,<1.0" \
"captum>=0.6.0" \
"matplotlib>=3.5.3" \
"plotly>=5.13.1" \
"python-kaleido==0.2.1"

And then install neuralprophet using pip:
pip install neuralprophet

